# Which steps I have to follow to configure Ubuntu server with Mac and Windows workstations?

Tags: login, samba, file-server

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server 10.04. I already have configured the basics and now I want to associate Windows and Mac OSX machines with the users created on Ubuntu so that when I login in one of these machines, the network be configured automatically with user home directory and permissions.

Currently the network is working with Samba, and the login is typed when a try to access the server. So, what I need now is the login associated with workstations initial login prompt.

Also, in Mac machines I want to automatically mount the network when I login.

I will appreciate if someone provide me some resources and best practices to do such a thing.

Comment: I see your edit. I happened to have pointed you to the right part of the documentation file. A *"Primary Domain Controller"* is a central instance that stores login information for Windows computers (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

For serving files to Windows machines you need [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29).

Samba can also handle user identities, but I think that Samba's passwords and access rights are entirely separate from those of regular Linux users.
[This](http://www.oregontechsupport.com/articles/samba.php) piece of documentation makes me think so, go to *"Samba as a Primary Domain Controller"*.

Disclaimer: I have really no knowledge on the subject. I have neither installed nor administrated any Samba server.

**Edit:**

This seems to be Sambas's main documentation:
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/index.html

Samba has a [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) module for providing login information for Linux. 
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/winbind.html 
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html

Comment: + 1 For the link. Thanks, I will try and return with my feedback.